# How to make a simple Ajax and PHP that will send a post from input?

Tags: php, ajax

How to make a simple Ajax and PHP that will send a post from input?

Comment: You are going to have to expand on that to get a good answer.  Do you mean that the form is posted via ajax when an input changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Include jQuery in the page
2. `jQuery.post('/foo.php', jQuery('form').serialize(), doSomethingWithResponse);`
3. `<?php doSomethingWith($_POST('name_of_input')); ?>`